# MySqli - не видит сервера

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

В общем есть скрипт, который использует файл mysql.php (код прикрепляю) в котором описан класс MySQL в php 5.6 все работало как часики, решил я значит обновить код до 7.0, изменил в этом файле все "mysql_" на "mysqli_" и все.
Постоянно Ошибочная конфигурация сервера (MySQL Off). Остальные файлы используют этот файл как
`$db = new MySQL(SQL_USER, SQL_PASS, SQL_BASE);`
Сервер не видит что-ли... Помогите понять причину.

Код файла

````
<?php
class MySQL
{
    public $host = SQL_HOST;
    private $port = 3306;
    private $sql = false; // Для запроса
    private $base = NULL; // БД
    public $user = false; ### Копия юзера БД, для бекапа
    public $pass = false; ### Копия пароля к БД, для бекапа
    public $db_name = false; ### Копия имени БД, для бекапа
    public $tme = 0; // Общее время работы БД
    public $all = 0; // Количество запросов
    public $sql_all = Array(); // Лог запросов
    private $sq = Array ('mc'=>'mysqli_connect',
            'msd'=>'mysqli_select_db',
            'mq'=>'mysqli_query',
            'mfa'=>'mysqli_fetch_assoc',
            'mr'=>'mysqli_result',
            'mfr'=>'mysqli_fetch_row',
            'mfrr'=>'mysqli_free_result'
            );
    
    public function __construct($user, $pwd, $db)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
        $this->pass = $pwd;
        $this->db_name = $db;
        
        $this->base = $this->sq['mc']( $this->host.':'.$this->port, $user, $pwd, true );
        $rs = $this->sq['msd']( $db, $this->base );
        
        if ( $rs==false ) die ( '<h1>Ошибочная конфигурация сервера (MySQL Off).</h1>' );
        $this->sq['mq']('SET NAMES cp1251');
    }
    
    private function error($q,$file='',$line='',$func='',$class='')
    {
    //  if ( defined('USERADMIN') )
        if ( @$_COOKIE['Admin'] )
        echo '<hr><b>MySQL Error:</b> '.mysqli_error().'<br>
        <b>Запрос:</b> '.$q.'<br>
        <b>File:</b> '.$file.'<br>
        <b>Line:</b> '.$line.'<br>
        <b>Function:</b> '.$func.'<br>
        <b>Class:</b> '.$class.'<hr>';
        
    }
    
    public function sql( $res, $file='', $line='', $func='', $class='' )
    {
        $t = microtime(true);
        $this->sql = $this->sq['mq']($res, $this->base);
        $t = microtime(true)-$t;
        if ( mysqli_error() ) $this->error($res,$file,$line,$func,$class);
        $this->tme += abs($t);
        $this->all++;
    //  $this->sql_all[] = $res;
        $this->sql_all[] = Array($res,$file,$line,$func,$class);
        return $this->sql;
    }
    
    public function sqla($res, $file='', $line='', $func='', $class='')
    {
        return $this->sq['mfa']( $this->sql( $res, $file, $line, $func, $class ) );
    }
    
    public function sqlr($res, $count=0, $file='', $line='', $func='', $class='')
    {
        if ($count==0) return @$this->sq['mr']($this->sql( $res, $file, $line, $func, $class ),0);
        else return @$this->sq['mr']($this->sql( $res, $file, $line, $func, $class ),$count);
    }
    
    public function sqla_id($res, $file='', $line='', $func='', $class='')
    {
        return $this->sq['mfr']( $this->sql( $res, $file, $line, $func, $class ) );
    }
    
    public function join($res, $file='', $line='', $func='', $class='')
    {
        
    }
    
    public function insert_id()
    {
        return mysqli_insert_id($this->base);
    }
    
    public function __destruct()
    {
    //  if (is_resource($this->sql)) $this->sq['mfrr']($this->sql); 
        mysqli_close($this->base);
    }
    
}

?>```
````

Comment: Афигеть... мой скрипт 10ти летней давности откопали в скрипте алонок))) подключись к базе с того же хоста где и скрипт, используя консоль) или phpmyadmin) кстати переменная `$sq` изначально там была, что ты там изменил хз)

Comment: Повторюсь, все работало на 5.6 и подрубаюсь я исключительно с того-же пк. Есть идея на этот скрипт, доделать нужно и обновить пых

Comment: phpmyadmin работает

Comment: посмотрите в документации какие и в какой последовательности передаются аргументы в функцию `mysqli_select_db`

Comment: так а что собственно не работает?) по коду - нет подключения к бд) мб ошибки какие есть

Comment: Вот и я не могу понять, как только меняю  ```'msd'=>'mysql_select_db',``` на ```'msd'=>'mysqli_select_db',``` Все, ошибка сервера

Comment: Возможно не установлено расширение php, `<?php phpinfo();`

Comment: Проверил, есть.
Client API library version mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 7cc7cc96e675f6d72e5cf0f267f48e167c2abb23 $
Active Persistent Links 0
Inactive Persistent Links 0
Active Links 0
Directive Local Value Master Value
mysqli.allow_local_infile Off Off
mysqli.allow_persistent On On
mysqli.default_host no value no value
mysqli.default_port 3306 3306
mysqli.default_pw no value no value
mysqli.default_socket no value no value
mysqli.default_user no value no value
mysqli.max_links Unlimited Unlimited
mysqli.max_persistent Unlimited Unlimited

Comment: Ответ может быть только один - Перестаньте использовать mysqli, и переключитесь на PDO.
Сами с нуля напишите скрипт, навешайте try-catch и займитесь отладкой.